# alpha function in R package "psych" doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: r, cronbachs-alpha

Ive always used the alpha function from the psych package to get Cronbachs alpha. I've written my script three days ago, it worked perfectly. Now it doesn't and it seems like the alpha function doesn't exist in psych anymore, only in ggplot (which is something completely different, when I ran the script I obviously got an error message because of the "unknown colour" because R read it as the ggplot function. Even though it worked perfectly fine as the psych function a few days ago.)
I definitely have the psych package installed and open, I can use other psych functions and alpha.ci and alpha2r (both from the psych package) are also suggested to me when I start typing alpha. But they don't seem to be doing the same thing as alpha.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

This is the error message that made me realise I was suddenly using the wrong function:

> Lehrererwartungen <- data_g9[, c("td0033a", "td0033b")]
>
> #Crohnbachs Alpha für Indextest
> alpha(Lehrererwartungen)
> Fehler: Unknown colour name: c(5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4,
> 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, NA, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, NA, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, NA, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3,

Comment: Why not move your R code into a project and initialize the proejct with the `rev` package.  Then you can download previous versions of the the packages that work the way you wanted them to, and then renv::snapshop your project.  This will capture the version of R you are using, and record metadata that lists all your packages, and versions.  If you install the previous version of the package that works for your code, it  will then be stored in your Project library rather than your Global/General LIbrary.  This will ensure that it will always run as you had designed it too.

Comment: ...and updates to your general/global library will not overwrite your project packages, to prevent this from potentially occuring again in the future.  See my post here about renv on stack overflow where your question is better posted:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036762/4615298

Comment: This is maybe more appropriate on StackOverflow, but first needs reproducible code!

Answer (score 7):

[The package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=psych) was last updated on June 23, 2023, and the documentation still contains the `alpha` function. Perhaps you loaded `ggplot2` **after** `psych`, which would have "overloaded" the name? Try using `psych::alpha` in your script and see if that works.